# CommaSeparatedIntegerField "Enter only digits separated by commas."

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-1.8

I'm using Django 1.8, when I try to save the record, "Enter only digits separated by commas." comes up. I'm guessing it's something to do with the cleaning, but I'm not sure.

I'm using in my model:

```
xHOURS = (("9", "9 am"),("10", "10 am"), ("11", "11 am"), ("12", "12 pm"),)

hours = models.CommaSeparatedIntegerField('Hours', max_length=200,)
```

and in my form:

```
hours = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=30,
                        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(choices=Evaluator.xHOURS),)

def clean_hours(self):
   field = ""
   for data in self.cleaned_data['hours']:
      field += data+","
   return field.lstrip(",")
```

Comment: Have you tried overriding the `clean` method? I think the `clean` method is called first and do the validation there.

Comment: You are passing in strings I believe... Not 100% convinced but have you tried `(9, "9 am")` etc?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is the problem, but I think you want `rstrip` instead of `lstrip` to remove the trailing comma. An alternative way to do it would be `return ",".join(self.cleaned_data['hours'])`.

Comment: Yes, I tried changing it to just intergers (9,"9 am"), I got rid of the "9 am" and just made it (9, 9), I tried starting at 0 ("0, 9am") no effect.  Now this is weirder, I changed it to rstrip, and I get the message "Enter only digits separated by commas.
Ensure this value has at most 30 characters (it has 35)."  How can I see what is in the value?  It shouldn't have 35 characters.

Comment: oh, thanks for cleaning up my text Sayse.

Comment: Anybody have any ideas on this?

Comment: I removed the form and now just use it as a multiselect dropdown, but I really would like to use the CheckboxSelectMultiple for aesthetics.  Anyone have any help for this?